# Using Parse.com pointers to query data from two classes , pointer value exception

Tags: java, android, pointers, parse-platform

I am new to Android development in general, and Parse.com particularly.

I'm trying to run a simple project where I have two classes (grades) and (subjects), where each of the subjects have a pointer to a certain grade (using objectId).
The if condition catches a ParseRequesException "gradePointer needs a pointer value"

I'm trying to display the list of subjects to a certain grade in a ListView.

Thanks!

Code:

```
 protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    final ParseObject grade = getGradeByGradeName("First secondry");
    sec1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String gradeId = grade.getObjectId();

            ParseQuery<ParseObject> subjectQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("subjects");
            subjectQuery.include("gradePointer");
            subjectQuery.whereEqualTo("gradePointer",gradeId);
            subjectQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                    if(e == null){
                        for(int i=0;i<subjectList.length;i++){
                            subjectList[i]=list.get(i).getString("name");


                        }
                        subjects.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,R
                                .layout.item,
                                subjectList));

                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: how does your gradePointer class looks like. does it have a column named  "gradePointer"?

Comment: The subject class has a Column of Pointer type named gradePointer.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy, your approach is bit wrong because of two things,

1. It complicates things.
2. It will consume two parse request(we should minimize these call as we can)

here's a way to get all the data within a single request, (replace grade column name in below query)

**Explanation**

since you are including the gradePointer you can directly query for the fields in that table with in the query.

```
 protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
 // final ParseObject grade = getGradeByGradeName("First secondry");
    sec1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //String gradeId = grade.getObjectId();

            ParseQuery<ParseObject> subjectQuery =   ParseQuery.getQuery("subjects");
            subjectQuery.include("gradePointer");
            subjectQuery.whereEqualTo("RelplaceThisWithGradeColumnName","First secondry");
            subjectQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                    if(e == null){
                        for(int i=0;i<subjectList.length;i++){
                            subjectList[i]=list.get(i).getString("name");


                        }
                        subjects.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,R
                                .layout.item,
                                subjectList));

                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, thanks it helped. But the list seems to return null for some reason. Any ideas why?

Comment: 1) Have you replaced "RelplaceThisWithGradeColumnName" with corredponding column in gades table? 2) there should be a column called gradePointer subjects table? 3) there shold be a value inside  grades table called "First secondry". If these conditions satify you must get data.

Comment: Yes to all, still null list value is returned.

Comment: Then may be there is a error. Check your e ` ParseException e`  value is null or not.